# Can somebody please explain the df -h result on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, disk-usage

I am very new to ubuntu or linux and I am using ssh to remotely access to the ubuntu vm. I have allocated 2GB for the disk on vm. When I used df -h to check the sizes,

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/pve-vm--1108--disk--0  974M  907M     0 100% /
none                               492K  4.0K  488K   1% /dev
tmpfs                               32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                               13G   92K   13G   1% /run
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1000
```

I am confused when I see 13G, 32G,... under the size column since I only allocated 2GB for disk. Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/pve-vm--1108--disk--0  974M  907M     0 100% /
```

The filesystem on that disk is currently sized at 974M and that amount is totally used up. But if you have increased the size of that virtual disk to 2 GB, then you need to also tell the filesystem to use the added space. You may be able to do it on-line, but may need more than one command, depending on what that disk actually is.

It looks like it might be a LVM logical volume named `vm-1108-disk-0` in a LVM volume group `pve`. You might want to run `lsblk`, `sudo pvs` and `sudo vgs` and add their outputs to your original post so we can give you exact commands to run.

Basically, you'll need to see if the 2 GB of disk space is already recognized by the system or not. But to identify the correct device from `lsblk` output, you might need the output of `sudo pvs` too.

The output of `sudo pvs` might be be similar to this:

```
PV                VG    Fmt  Attr PSize       PFree 
/dev/<something>  pve   lvm2 a--  <about 1G>  0
```

If so, and the size of `/dev/<something>` as indicated by `lsblk` is more like 2 GB, then you'll need to do a `sudo pvresize /dev/<something>` to tell LVM it can take up the new space.  But if `lsblk` also shows about 1G size for `/dev/<something>`, then you will need to do one or two things first:

- If `/dev/<something>` is a whole-disk device, like `/dev/sdX` where X is just one or more letters, then you might need to tell the system to re-check the size of the device, with `echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/block/<something>/device/rescan`.
- If `/dev/<something>` is a partition device, like `/dev/sdXN` where X is one or more letters and N is a number, or like `/dev/<some device>pN` then there is a partition table to deal with too, which can be a pain. If that disk has just one partition, or the partition that holds the LVM physical volume is the last partition on the disk, the `growpart` command in the `cloud-guest-utils` package might offer an easy way to extend the partition on-line.

After `pvresize` (or if the 2G space is already under LVM control), `sudo pvs` might look like this:

```
PV                VG    Fmt  Attr PSize       PFree 
/dev/<something>  pve   lvm2 a--  <about 2G>  <about 1G>
```

At this point, the added space is available to the LVM and you can add it to the logical volume on-line with e.g.:

```
sudo lvextend -l 100%FREE -r /dev/mapper/pve-vm--1108--disk--0
```

Instead of using the option `-l 100%FREE` to give all the currently free space to the specified logical volume, you could also use the option `-L +1G` or `-L 2G` to specify either the amount to grow the filesystem by, or the new size to grow to.

The `-r` option tells `lvextend` to also automatically extend the filesystem on-line if possible; it will use `fsadm resize` for this. If the `fsadm` command is not available, you could omit the `-r` option to `lvextend`, but then you would have to use a filesystem-type-specific tool to tell the filesystem to take up the new space, e.g. `sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/pve-vm--1108--disk--0` for `ext2`/`ext3`/`ext4` filesystems, or `xfs_growfs /` for XFS filesystems.

Answer (score 1):

Only the first of these ( / ) is a disk.

Note that the device for all but the first one is "none" or "tmpfs".
The "none" is a generated filesystem (type devtmpfs).  The rest ("tmpfs") are ram disks.

The first one (/dev/mapper...) is also a virtual disk but it is backed by a real (VM) disk.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So does 100% mean, my disk space has totally used up?

Comment: @itayush yes, the disk partition is full

Comment: @itayush Ubuntu, for whatever reason, keeps _quite a lot_ of the disk unallocated. You need to expand the logical volume to claim the space.

Comment: The other answer well covers the LVM details to fix your disk space usage.  As currently configured, it is full, but see the other answer...

Comment: @roaima no, that's not quite right.  The filesystem is certainly full, but we can't tell from this if the filesystem is the same size as the partition.  It's a good guess, but it's still only a guess.